# How to switch to the next tab of the TabbedPage on clicking button in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm having 2 content pages inside the TabbedPage. One content page contains ListView. I want to switch to other tab on selecting the item in the ListView. How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 2):

Listen for the `ListView.ItemSelected` event and forward it to your TabbedPage.
You can change the current active page using the `TabbedPage.CurrentPage` property.

```
public class MasterPage : TabbedPage
{
    public MasterPage()
    {
        var page1 = new Page1();
        var page2 = new Page2();

        page1.ItemSelected += (sender, args) =>
        {
            if (args.SelectedItem is string answer && answer.Equals("Yes"))
            {
                CurrentPage = page2;
            }
        };

        Children.Add(page1);
        Children.Add(page2);
    }
}

public class Page1 : ContentPage
{
    public event EventHandler<SelectedItemChangedEventArgs> ItemSelected;

    public Page1()
    {
        Title = "Page1";

        var labelQuestion = new Label()
        {
            Text = "Do you want to switch to Page2?"
        };

        var listViewAnswers = new ListView()
        {
            ItemsSource = new string[] { "Yes", "No" },
            ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
            {
                var cell = new TextCell();
                cell.SetBinding(TextCell.TextProperty, ".");
                return cell;
            })
        };

        listViewAnswers.ItemSelected += (sender, args) => ItemSelected?.Invoke(this, args);

        Content = new StackLayout()
        {
            Children =
            {
                labelQuestion,
                listViewAnswers
            }
        };
    }
}

public class Page2 : ContentPage
{
    public Page2()
    {
        Title = "Page2";

        Content = new StackLayout()
        {
            Children =
            {
                 new Label()
                    {
                        Text = "Page2"
                    }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: @Abhishek You should accept this as the answer by clicking the green checkmark on the left side.

Answer (score 0):

A simple example that I can give you is this:

```
public class MainTabbedPage : TabbedPage {
    readonly Page tab1Page;
    readonly Page tab2Page;

    public MainTabbedPage() {
        tab1Page = new Page1() { Title = "Tab 1 title", Icon="circle.png" };
        tab2Page =new Page2() { Title = "Tab 2 title", Icon="square.png" };

        // To change tab order, just shuffle these Add calls around.
        Children.Add(tab1Page);
        Children.Add(tab2Page);
    }

    public void SwitchToTab1() {
        CurrentPage = tab1Page;
    }
    public void SwitchToTab2() {
        CurrentPage = tab2Page;
    }
}



public class Page1 : ContentPage {
    public Page1() {
        var button = new Button() {
            Text = "Switch to Tab 2",
        };
        button.Clicked += async (sender, e) => {
            var tabbedPage = this.Parent as TabbedPage;
            tabbedPage.SwitchToTab2();
        };
        Content = new StackLayout { 
            Children = {
                button,
            }
        };
    }
}
```